# Как найти строку с максимальным значением в одном столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

У меня есть фрейм данных по фильмам: название, актёрский состав, жанры, бюджет и т.д. Нужно найти фильм с максимальным бюджетом. Я нашел максимальный бюджет.

Но как мне сопоставить с его с названием фильма?

Текущий код:

```
data = pd.read_csv('movie_bd_v5.csv')
top_budget = data['budget'].max()
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
top_budget_movie = data.nlargest(1, columns=["budget"])["name"]
```

---

**UPD:**
можно сделать менее эффективно (в два шага) - сначала находим максимум и после этого выбираем строки в которых бюджет максимальный:

```
max_budget = data['budget'].max()
res = df.query("budget == @max_budget")["name"]
```

PS в этом случае если существует более одного фильма с максимальным (одинаковым) бюджетом, то вам придется самому позаботиться о дубликатах...

Comment: спасибо! а как просто найти значение второго элемента, зная значение другого элемента? например, я определил точное значение budget. как мне зная его найти name с таким значением budget?

Comment: буду знать, помогли)